# What are the settings accepted by the underscore templates?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, template-engine

The [`_.template()`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function accepts `settings` as a third argument, allowing you to change a few things about how do the templates work, including making the templates more Moustache-like. But is this all the settings can do? Can you provide a full list of keys and their meanings for the settings object? And is it possible to compile settings into a template (since the `data` argument goes before `settings`, it seems that providing settings along with a template would result in underscore trying to apply a template immediately, assuming settings to be the data).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But is this all the settings can do?

Yes, all possible `settings` are mentioned in [the docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template). You can read the [annoted source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-134) as well.

> Can you provide a full list of keys and their meanings for the settings object?

- `interpolate`: regex to match expressions that should be interpolated verbatim
- `escape`: regex to match expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped
- `evaluate`: regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without insertion into the resulting string.
- `variable`: A variable name to access the data as properties, instead of using a `with` statement

> And is it possible to compile settings into a template?

Yes. Simply pass any falsy value (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, …) for `data` and the method will return a template function instead of rendering it right away.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the annotated source (I highly recommend it, there's a lot of great explanations there), the three options for settings are evaluate, interpolate and escape. Here's a link to the templateSettings object:

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-131

I'm not sure I fully understand the question about compiling settings into a template, but you can set global template settings (so you don't have to pass it in as an argument to the template method, like this:

```
_.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
      evaluate: /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g
  };
```

Sorry if that didn't answer your question, but hopefully the annotated source will shed some light.